# child.postMessage not working in IE11 compatible web application in Microsoft Edge

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, popup, microsoft-edge, popupwindow

I am trying to communicate between a IE 11 compatible web application and pop-up window opened using window.open. Below is the code I am using in IE11 compatible web application:

```
var options = 'titlebar=no,resizable=no';
var url = '<different app url but within same org>';
var child = window.open(url,'window',options);
child.postMessage({message: 'requestResult'},'*');
```

This is working in chrome and IE, but it's failing in Microsoft Edge. I cannot receive message in child popup window in Edge.
Can anyone please check and let me know why it's failing in Edge.

Answer (score 0):

I think the page opened by `window.open()` should be running in Edge instead of Edge IE mode. If this is the case, you need to configure the opened page in the Edge IE mode site list to achieve your needs.

You can even simply try to output the child window handle: `child` object. You will find that it is **Null** instead of [window object]. This is because the two pages are running in different browsers (IE and Edge).

For more details about how to Configure IE mode, you could refer to this doc:[Configure IE mode policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode-policies)
.

Comment: Yes this is the case window.open is returning  null. Let me try to configure IE mode policies.

Comment: What is Microsoft Edge policy template, I am already on latest version of Edge do I need to install something else.

Comment: The Microsoft Edge policy template is used to manage all group policies for Edge, you need some configuration to complete it, something like this: [simple shootscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TagMK.png).